# How can I see the number of visitors in my website via CLI

Tags: command-line, logs, webserver

How can I find out the number of visitors in real time in my website? I'd like to access to it via SSH, so it should be some CLI programs.

In the worst case scenario I was thinking to analyse the number of IPs in the Apache/Nginx access file for a range of the last 5 min or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most web statistics tools summarise the log over a period of 24 hours or a month. The simplest cli ncurses-based one is [goaccess](https://goaccess.io/).

For an instant view of your apache server current cpu usage and threads there is [server-status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) which you could retrieve via curl, in html. See a [live](https://httpd.apache.org/server-status) demo (beware large file). Nginx has a similar feature.

You might also look at answers on our sister web site [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) such as [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/4852/53377) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/39012/53377).

Answer (score 1):

This is filthy, but simple :
$ awk '{print $8}' < request_log | sort -u | wc -l
To do the last 5 minutes bit, try: 
$ grep -A 9999999 'five minutes ago string' awk '{print $8}' < request_log | sort -u | wc -l
obviously $8 is the position of the client ip in each line of your log.
There are lots of log analyzers, many of which are free. Don't pay for log analyzers of text logs.