# cli real-time monitoring of web server traffic per second over time (ncurses)

Tags: command-line, monitoring, nginx, webserver, ncurses

Is there a tool that can be used to monitor the traffic a web server is processing in real-time from the command line?

I'm looking for a cli ncurses tool like `nload`, but one that can show the requests per second going to a web server like nginx or apache (or a cache like varnish) via mod_status or stub_status.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/295880/419003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like `nload`, but you an get a ton of useful information from your web server's access logs (NCSA, W3C, squid,or any user-defined custom log format) in an ncurses-based tool called `goaccess`

In Debian, run:

```
sudo apt-get install goaccess
goaccess /path/to/access.log -c
```

It will look something like this

[image: goacess cli]